# Should I use strdup() or just assign an address?

Tags: c

I have a structure in which one of the members is a pointer to char.

Lets say a structure looks like

```
  struct{
         int a;
         char *cp;
  }X;
```

I am a bit confused if I should do

```
 X.cp = str;
```

or

```
X.cp = strdup(str);
```

str is a string.

What would be the criteria that will decide which implementation to follow?

Comment: It comes down to who or what is going to own the region of memory that `cp` is going to point to. Is `X` going to own it? Or is something else?

Comment: It's simple. Do you want a reference to the original `str` or do you want to make a copy of the string?

Comment: Side-note: if `a` is the length of the memory, I would favor `malloc` and `memcpy` - knowing the length should reduce the operations required by `strdup`.

Comment: Only you can answer this question.

Answer (score 3):

Let's assume that `str` points to the address 0x111111 and that the string *beginning* at that address is "foobar".

After doing `X.cp = str;`, the value of X.cp will be 0x111111 i.e. X.cp "points" to 0x111111. At that point `printf("%s",X.cp)` and `printf("%s",str)` will both print foobar and `printf("%p",X.cp)` and `printf("%p",str)` will both print 0x111111. The only thing that will have changed in memory is the value of `X.cp` (which is just 0x111111, NOT the string itself).

After doing `X.cp = strdup(str);`, the value of X.cp will NOT be 0x111111, it will instead be a newly allocated address; let's assume it's 0x222222.
Furthermore, the string stored at 0x111111 will have been copied to the SEVEN addresses beginning at 0x222222 (i.e. 'f' 'o' 'o' 'b' 'a' 'r' '\0'). So, in this situation there are two changes to memory: the value of X.cp and the newly allocated block of addresses comprising a string. In this case all the `printf`s from the previous case will produce the same output here EXCEPT for `printf("%p",X.cp)`, it will print `0x222222`.

These two ways of assigning to X.cp serve very different purposes. The first case should be used if you want changes to X.cp to be seen when accessing str and vice-versa. On the other hand, the second case should be used when you want to be able to change X.cp and str independently. Be careful with the first case: if you deallocate one of X.cp or str then you must not try to de-reference the other or you will get a segfault.

Remember that "strings" are special. They are NOT data types in C. They are blocks of `chars` in memory terminated with a `'\0'` `char`.
This is why you SHOULD NOT do something like `*(X.cp) = *str` (unless you really just want to copy one character).

Lastly, I should note that you call your variable `X.cp` which might be a bad name if you don't use `strdup()` since strdup() is a copy AKA "cp".

Answer (score 2):

Use `strdup` if the original string can be destroyed or reused before you're done using `X.cp`.

For instance, if `str` is a local array in the function, and you return from the function while `X` is still being used, you need to make a copy of the string. Or if `str` is a dynamically-allocated string, and the function calls `free(str);`, you need to make a copy of it.

If `str` is a buffer that you read each line into, you need to make a copy because you're going to overwrite it.

If changes made to the original `str` contents should automatically be reflected in `X.cp`, or vice versa, then you should just assign the pointer.

Comment: What if str is a global variable?

Comment: It depends on how you're using them, like I said. If changes to one should be seen in the other, you should assign the pointer. If they should act independently, you need to make a copy.

Comment: @Nguaial If it's global and you want a pointer to that global, store the pointer. If you want to be safe from changes to that global, copy it. Also consider whether it should be global.

Answer (score 0):

If you know you control `str`, then use a pointer. Like if you allocated `str` inside your own function and aren't storing it anywhere else there's no point in copying it.

If you want to share changes to `str` with others, use a pointer.

If you want to isolate yourself from other people's uses of `str`, do a `strdup`.

---

Sometimes you can know this, often you can't, but the person using your struct does know. Let the user decide. Write your functions to take a `char *` and use that pointer. Document that your function will use the original pointer.

```
X* X_new( char *str ) {
    X* x = malloc( sizeof(X) );
    x->cp = str;
    x->a = 42; // I don't know what a is for

    return x;
}

// The caller lets x control str, x->cp is str.
X* x = X_new( str );

// The caller passes in a copy of str, x->cp and str are independent of each other.
X* y = X_new( strdup(str) );
```

By using the pointer, it allows the user to decide to pass in a pointer or a copy. If `X_new` did `strdup(str)` the user would have no say.

Answer (score -1):

perfect code :

```
X.cp=malloc(strlen(str)+1);
if(X.cp==NULL)
{
    printf("not enough memory \n");
    return 0;
}
memset(X.cp,0,strlen(str)+1);
X.cp = strdup(str);

/**
*code
**/

if(X.cp)
   free(x.cp);
```

Comment: strdup() already does malloc() and strcpy().  There is no need to do malloc() and memset().  And strlen() is very dangerous to use. What if str is not NUL character terminated?

Comment: after writing your code  you can use klocwork to check memory leak and you will be noticed that this is the right code. Try klocwork its a good tool. PS : i forget +1 in malloc and strlen.

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question, which is asking whether to copy a string or just store a pointer to the existing string.